# Insert three.js independient scripts in reveal.js slides

Tags: javascript, three.js, reveal.js

I want to introduce several three.js 3D models within different reveal.js slides. So far I achieved it partially. In each slide I introduce:

```
<section>
    <script src="three_r84/model1.js"></script>
    <div id="model1" width="950" height="600" data-prevent-swipe></div>         
</section>
```

And model1.js file is the following:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame;
    })();

    function animateScene() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animateScene);
        renderScene();
    }

    function startScene() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('model1');
        render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true});

        render.setClearColor(0x191919, 0);

        var canvasWidth = canvas.getAttribute('width');
        var canvasHeight = canvas.getAttribute('height');
        render.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        canvas.appendChild(render.domElement);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var aspect = canvasWidth / canvasHeight;

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, aspect);
        camera.position.set(15, 10, 15);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        scene.add(camera);
        
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
            controls.enableDamping = true;
            controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
            controls.enableZoom = true;                 
                
// concrete columns             
            // define columns geometry
                var columnGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.25, 3, 0.4);

            // define columns colors
                function hsl(h, s, l) {
                    return (new THREE.Color()).setHSL(h, s, l);
                }
            // define columns position & pass data (geometry, color, position) to create foundation function
                {
                    makeInstanceColumn(columnGeometry, hsl(0 / 8, 1, .5), 0, -0, 0);
                }
            
            // create columns
                function makeInstanceColumn(columnGeometry, color, x, z, y) {
                    [THREE.BackSide, THREE.FrontSide].forEach((side) => {
                        var columnMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                            color,
                            opacity: 0.5,
                            transparent: true,
                            side,
                        });

                        var column = new THREE.Mesh(columnGeometry, columnMaterial);
                        scene.add(column);

                        column.position.set(x, z, y);
                    });
                }           
// light
  function addLight(x, z, y) {
    var color = 0xFFFFFF;
    var intensity = 1;
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(x, z, y);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  addLight(-1,  2,  4);
  addLight( 1, -1, -2);
    }
    function renderScene() {
        controls.update();
        render.render(scene, camera);
    }
    startScene();
    animateScene();
    renderScene(); 
});
```

It works, although I had to insert another slide between to consecutive 3D models. Otherwise they appear in the same slide (as an overlay) even though the "canvas"es are created in different "section"s. <del>And also it does not work more than two times.</del> However, the main problem is that I am unable to interact with the first model. The OrbitControl, seems to be linked with the <del>second</del> last 3D model, which slide I have not yet visualize but rotates, pans and zooms it.

I have read that there is a "slidechanged" event listener. I think that I should insert it somewhere in the code but I do not know how and where. I tried subtituting `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) ...` from the beginning of the script with "`document.addEventListener('slidechanged', function(event) ...` but it did not work. Silly me, I suppose I should use `Reveal.on ...` but I do not figure how.

BTW I am using a quite old version of three.js (r84). I do not need the full potential of three.js neither I can use it, because I need to show it in an old iPad (iOS 9.3.5) I know there is an [example of combining three.js and reveal.js](https://www.dimroc.com/reveal.js-threejs/). It uses and even older version (r59) but I can not simply swap my scripts for its scripts, because it does not recognize some of the commands, e.g. `BoxGeometry` and other stuff.

I would like to do something similar, but I seek for guidance and advice. Does someone face something similar? Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, I also use a different reveal.js version than the provided example, so the way stuff is handled also differs.